# Sveltekit not placing form value on input field (using use:enhance)

Tags: html, forms, svelte, sveltekit, svelte-3

I'm facing a kind of weird situation. I've got the following form:

```
<script>
    import RecordForm from "../../../components/forms/RecordForm.svelte";

    /* data returned from load function in +page.server.js */
    export let data;

    /* data returned from actions function in +page.server.js */
    export let form;

</script>

<RecordForm mode="edit" formData={ {...data, ...form} }/>
```

Nothing out of ordinary here. This is an edit form so I'm simply combining `data` (which is the info the form is first loaded with) and `form` (which is the data returned from the submit action).

When the form is first loaded all the fields in it are populated as expected.

When the form is submitted and errors are found, then the action returns the `formData` as expected and it is passed to the form, now, most fields are populated except two.

The weird part is the following: After noticing that those fields were not being populated, I created a `div` on top of them and placed the same statement there that the one in the input field. That `div` displays the correct data (see screeenshot).

My form uses `use:enhance`, when I remove it, it behaves correctly.

[image]

Here is one of the fields:

```
<!-- Title -->
        <div class="basis-1/2 form-control w-full">
            <label class="label">
                <span class="label-text">Title <span class="required-field">*</span></span>
            </label>
            <div>HERE {formData?.data?.title}</div>
            <input
                    name="title"
                    id="title"
                    type="text"
                    value={ formData?.data?.title || "" }
                    class="input input-bordered w-full max-w-xs"/>

            <label for="title" class="label">
                {#if formData?.errors?.title}
                    <span class="label-text-alt text-error">{ formData?.errors?.title[0]}</span>
                {/if}
            </label>
        </div>
```

Again, notice that
`<div>HERE {formData?.data?.title}</div>`
displays the correct data while
`value={ formData?.data?.title || "" }` isn't showing anything.

If I print the `data` object returned from the action it shows the correct data:

```
{
  data: {
    barcode: '101010101010111',
    title: 'Test Record',
    original_release_year: '2008',
    original_release_date: '',
    reissue_release_date: ''
  }
}
```

Any idea what's going on? I already tried shutting down the dev server (sometimes the auto refresh doesn't work as expected) but still getting the same result.

**NOTE**: It is happening for all input values of type text, type number works fine.

Somehow it works for number input fields such as:

```
<input
                    name="owned_copies"
                    id="owned-copies"
                    type="number"
                    value={ formData?.data?.owned_copies || 1 }
                    class="input input-bordered w-full max-w-xs" />
```

Comment: It might be helpful to temporarily set your input values to `formData.data.title` and `formData.data.barcode` to see if the renderer throws an error (if for instance either `formData` or `formData.data` are undefined when evaluated), which might in turn help you locate the source of your problem.

Comment: same result. Not sure what's going on, I've got other text fields and they work just fine also pulling data from `formData.data`.

Comment: this seems to be a known issue in svelte https://github.com/sveltejs/kit/issues/8513 . Removing `enhance` temporarily while a fix is pushed.

Answer (score 0):

Try to change that one value into this which can help you to debug more

```html
<input
   ...
   value={ `HERE ${formData?.data?.title || "nothing here"}` }
/>
```

The problem here could also be that you have to use `bind:value={formData?.data?.title || ""}`

Comment: The `HERE` piece was only to signal that the piece of data was in the `div`, no really needed in the field.  Anyway, cannot use `bind` since you can only bind to an identifier or a member expression. Furthermore, I've got other input fields that are configured just as the one in the example and they work just fine.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, you didn't post the server-side code that is processing your form input, but if I were to hazard a guess, you probably aren't wrapping your error responses in a `fail()`. See how to use `use:enhance` with fail using this tutorial page. The relevant code lives in `src/routes/+page.server.ts`: https://learn.svelte.dev/tutorial/progressive-enhancement